# Cannot add guest to O365 Group from Outlook 2016

Tags: outlook, microsoft-office-365, groups

According to the documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guest-access-in-office-365-groups-bfc7a840-868f-4fd6-a390-f347bf51aff6) group owners should be able to add guest users to O365 groups.  In my case, I see an error stating

> We couldn't find the person you were looking for

However, I *can* add guests via Outlook Web by clicking the "Add Members" icon.

Why can I not add guests from Outlook 2016?

Here are the relevant settings:

Sharing is enabled:
[image]

The Group is an O365 Group
[image]

Outlook still won't let me add external users:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure it's an **Office 365 Group**, instead of normal Distribution Group or Security Group.

Also, we will get an warning about "*No suggestions found, but fell free to enter any email address*", then press "Enter" to add it as member.[image]

Comment: Original post updated with more details or my issue.